# Converting a polars Date column to only Months

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to convert an existing column in my polars dataframe from Date to Month. The documentation [here](https://%20https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.ExprDateTimeNameSpace.month.html?highlight=onth#polars.internals.expr.ExprDateTimeNameSpace.month) is not clear to me on how to call such methods.

In pandas it looks like this to convert Date -> Month:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df['column']).month.astype(np.int16)
```

What is the polars equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `dt` object first before applying `.month()`

```py
from datetime import date
dates = pl.date_range(date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 3, 1), "1d", name="drange")
months = dates.dt.month()
```

Comment: You can toss in a cast(pl.Int16()) to match their astype at the end

Answer (score 1):

If the `column` is already in the polars `pl.Datetime` format:

```
df = (
     df
    .with_column(pl.col("column").dt.strftime("%b").alias("month"))
    )
```